# How can I stop the 'bloom' effect shifting direction in eevee?

Tags: camera, eevee-render-engine

I have a short space scene that I've included some camera shake on. Everything looks great, but the bloom effect I have on the sun shifts direction with the camera movement!
Have attached a short gif that demonstrates the problem, first at normal speed, then frame by frame.

Any ideas on how I might reduce or get rid of this?

Thank you in advance!

[image: Shaky Bloom]

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: Try disabling bloom and using a glare node instead in the compositor, if that still not helps then you can use a gradient map to create bloom effect instead.

Comment: If you don't know how then you can just ask by commenting or tell if it works or not.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Will give the first a try!

Comment: The glare node is ok, but loses a lot of the more interesting aspects of the bloom (Chromatic aberrations, smooth light falloff etc). I'm not sure how I would go about creating a bloom effect with a gradient map, could you point me in the right direction? Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: You can add a material to sun and put it in front of planet by only moving it on 1 axis pointing towards the planet, then you can use a radial gradient as a factor to mix an emissions shader with a transparent shader, you can add an color ramp or rgb curves to control fall off and smoothness, now you'll get some basic sun like looking shader for going even further you can use object coordinates and manipulate them using different texture to get your desired results, this is a really flexible method.

Comment: Ok will give that a go, hopefully it fixes it!

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the help, none of the solutions fixed what I needed unfortunately.

However I did manage to fix the problem, and for anyone who is facing a similar issue, here's how I did it.

I figured out that the way bloom was being calculated was in relation to the emitters angle to the camera. With my shake being set on the x axis, small rotations were being amplified by the bloom effect because the angle in relation to the camera was changing and as a result, so was the direction it was 'blooming' the light.

To fix it, I made one very simple change, instead of a shake in the rotation, I applied the effect to the translation in the z axis. The motion feels pretty much exactly the same, but instead of it changing the angle the camera points at, it moves the whole camera up and down a bit. It's worth pointing out there will still be some shift in the bloom effect as the translation still adjusts the angle a bit, but its a lot less noticeable now.

Mission accomplished!